# Smooth representatives of two free homotopy classes of loops on a surface that intersect transversally

Tags: differential-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I am reading a paper on closed curves of a closed-oriented surface, where the following Fact comes without proof.

> **Fact:** Let $\Sigma$ be closed connected orientable surface. Let $\widehat\pi(\Sigma)$ be the free homotopy classes of loops on
> $\Sigma$. Consider $x,y\in  \widehat\pi(\Sigma)$. Then there is a
> representative $\alpha$ of $x$ and a representative $\beta$ of $y$
> such that the following hold:
>
> $(1)$ Both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the images of some smooth maps
> $\Bbb S^1\to \Sigma$.
>
> $(2)$ Each point of $\alpha\cap \beta$ is a point of transversal
> intersection, i.e., each point $p\in\alpha\cap \beta$ has a small open neighborhood $U_p$ such that $U_p\cap (\alpha\cup \beta)$ is homeomorphic to $(\Bbb R\times 0)\cup (0\times \Bbb R)$.

My question is how to prove the above Fact. My idea is to use geodesic representatives of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not proved in that paper because it is a standard elementary theorem of differential topology known as the [transversality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem).

You should be able to find the proof in most differential topology textbooks. I also found [these lecture notes](https://schapos.people.uic.edu/MATH549_Fall2015_files/Survey%20Charlotte.pdf) by a search for *transversality theorem*.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to say that $x$ and $y$ are free homotopy classes of closed curves, and these closed curves may not be embedded (simple) closed curves.

Comment: Well, transversality is a local property, and the proof should therefore still work.